# Customer Portal Login from External Page

Tags: api, customer-portal, login

I need to create a Customer Portal login page from an external site (outside salesforce domain).

Use case...

My login page is https://www.mydomain.com/customer/login where the user can enter ID/PW
Once ID/PW match from salesforce the user will be redirected to https://mycompany.force.com/portal_page/ (the actual customer portal page from salesforce)

The external site is in .NET

I would really appreciate if someone can point me to any documents, guidance, tips, API, etc. I'm a .NET developer, and it's my first time working with Salesforce.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to host the login page, you can just add a custom domain to your community: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_communities_implementation.meta/salesforce_communities_implementation/communities_custom_domain_URL.htm

You could also implement SSO using SAML in order to maintain the same credentials from the other page: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=networks_auth_configure_saml.htm&language=en_US